# Import emails to Gmail received by another email address only from now on?

Tags: gmail

From past experience, if I still remember correctly, when importing to a Gmail address from another email address, all mails received by the other email address before and after the importing will all be transferred to the Gmail address.

If I am correct, can I choose to just import to the Gmail address the emails that will be received by the other email address, instead of those email that have already been received by the other email address?

PS: After setting up importing, can I choose to cancel the importing, i.e. not transferring the emails received by the email address to the Gmail one, sometime in the future, for example, one month later?

Comment: If you must import import all and never go back. If you must use another email address use IMAP. Furthermore why would you want to keep using another email address? Take the leap!

Comment: what is your goal with this import? Do you want to check email or do you want to import everything? Google [discusses the difference](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56283&topic=1669014&ctx=topic)

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: I think I just  want to forward emails from another email address to my gmail for one month from now. After that, I want to stop my gmail account receiving emails of the other account.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to see the email in another account use the [mail fetcher within gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21288) This will pull the data from the POP3 enabled account.

If you configure the fetcher to label all the emails from the pop3 account, and you leave all the emails on the pop3 server; then when you want to turn it off in a month, you can easily do so.

If you want to delete any messages from the pop3 account from gmail you can use the label to quickly find them and archive/delete them.

Setting up the mail fetcher:

1. Click the gear icon in the upper right, then select Settings.
2. Open the Accounts and Import tab.
3. In the Check mail using POP3 section, click Add POP3 email account.
4. Enter the full email address of the account you'd like to access, then click Next Step.
5. Gmail will populate sample settings, but we recommend checking with your other provider to learn the correct server name and port. Enter your Password.
6. Decide whether to:

   - Leave a copy of retrieved messages on the server
   - Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail
   - Label incoming messages
   - Archive incoming messages
7. Click Add Account.
8. Once your account has been added successfully, you'll have the option of setting it as a custom From address. This allows you to compose messages in Gmail, but have them appear to be sent from your other email account. Click Yes to set up a custom From address.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if fetch can be used to only fetch future new emails received by the other email account, without transferring existing emails previously received by the other email account?